# How to scale Dygraph on a page correctly?

Tags: reactjs, dygraphs

I noticed that in initiating a Dygraph object width and height can only be set to pure integers. I'm not really sure what this is a measurement of. It doesn't scale when I resize my browser. I would like to set it to be something along the lines of height: 70% instead of height: 700. Is this possible?

Comment: http://dygraphs.com/tests/resize.html is an example of a graph that resizes with the browser, I'm sure you could put it in a container div with a % age value

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered these problems as well. I found that the resize example didn't help me much either.

After a few hours of struggle, I did manage to find a solution, though. All of it is required to get the dygraph to fill the parent div, but you can (of course) change the parent width from 60%.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
    <div id={this.props.containerId} className="dygraphChart"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
  position: relative;
  width: 60%;
}

.dygraphChart {
  position: absolute;
  left: 1px;
  right: 1px;
  top: 1px;
  bottom: 1px;
  min-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: This didn't really work for me (the graph makes a half hearted attempt at scaling with my window but not quite). I do understand the idea behind what you're saying so that does help! Also I assume that id={this.props.containerID} is where you are calling whatever graph var you initiated.

Comment: However, what did work somewhat better for me was just having .dygraphChart have properties (position:absolute, max-width:50%, max-height:50%). This is obviously not exactly a solution so I'm going to continue fiddling with this!